# Disabling submit, but submitting form first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

```
<script>function lockoutSubmit(button) {
    var oldValue = button.value;

    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    button.value = '...processing...';

    setTimeout(function(){
        button.value = oldValue;
        button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 3000)
}</script>
```

So that's the script I'm using for disable (found here on Stack Overflow).

This is my update condition:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['coin'])){

        $coin="UPDATE users SET coins = coins + 100 WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";

        $coin_in=mysqli_query($conn,$coin);
    }?>
```

Here is where I add `onclick` to input:

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Get Coins" name="coin" onclick="lockoutSubmit(this)" >
 </form>
```

This script disables the button after clicking it, which I want but the problem is, when I add the `onclick` to the input `UPDATE` from `if` condition, it does not work. Basically when I click submit, nothing happens, it only disables it. I'm new to JavaScript and don't know is it even possible to combine it like this...Any ideas/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return false to onclick it won't submit the form.

So just add a `return false` to **lockoutSubmit()** and manually submit with `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();` after the delay.

Comment: <script>function lockoutSubmit(button) { var oldValue = button.value; button.setAttribute('disabled', true); button.value = '...processing...'; setTimeout(function(){ button.value = oldValue; button.removeAttribute('disabled'); }, 3000) }</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
<form name="myform" action="formaction" method="post"> 

<input type="submit" value="Get Coins" name="coin" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit();lockoutSubmit(this)" /> </form>
```

Or if you know CSS can make anchor button

```
<a="JavaScript: document.forms['myform'].submit()" on click="lockoutSubmit(this);" />
```